# Tinier string between two substrings

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to parse IRC logs, like this one :

```
2013-09-26T01:52:40  <Shan-x> some stuff
```

I want to have the pseudo, so I use `re` :

```
re.search('%s(.*)%s' % ('<', '>'), s).group(1)
```

But if the log is like this :

```
2013-09-26T01:52:40  <Shan-x> some stuff > foo bar
```

Then, I obtain this : `Shan-x> some stuff`. How can I parse to have only the pseudo ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make the `.*` *non greedy* by adding a `?` to the `*` quantifier:

```
re.search('%s(.*?)%s' % ('<', '>'), s).group(1)
```

Now the `.` matches the *minimum* number of characters that satisfies the pattern, rather than the default maximum.

Not sure why you use string interpolation here, though; for static characters, just use:

```
re.search('<(.*?)>', s).group(1)
```

You could also capture all characters that do not match the end character:

```
re.search('<([^>]*)>', s).group(1)
```

Here `[^>]` forms a character class matching any character that is *not* in the class; so any character that is not `>` would qualify.